# I am getting Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean even with @springbootapplication

Tags: java, spring

This is my main class 
I am getting this error even though i am using the springbootApplication annotation that should autowire all dependecies

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.valentine.model","com.valentine.messenger"})
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.valentine.gram",
    "com.valentine.service", "com.valentine"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.valentine.dao")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

Below is my stack trace and pom file , this is a modular project so i am posting the main pom file

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-11-09 23:10:47.131 ERROR 9266 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.valentine.gram.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:19) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:204) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at
```

Now the pom file is below

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.valentine.mygram</groupId>
            <artifactId>main-app</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--spring-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--servlets-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Any suggestions of what the problem might be and how i could solve the problem

Comment: have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231736/applicationcontextexception-unable-to-start-servletwebserverapplicationcontext/50232382

Comment: yes it suggests spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: none

Comment: but mine is a web app so i cant say none to web application type

Comment: @Deadpool so what other options

Comment: @Deadpool yes it worked but there is no servlet and  i need it to expose my rest end points

Comment: try another solutions, but i'm not sure about this

Comment: @valik Did you try answer ?

Comment: yes the issue was the dependecies versions  should be gotten from boots repo and not written by hand the idea came from your answer thank you

Comment: @valik My pleasure !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I know in spring boot there is no need to use extra annotation like

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.valentine.model","com.valentine.messenger"})
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.valentine.gram",
    "com.valentine.service", "com.valentine"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.valentine.dao")
```

I think `@SpringBootApplication` is enough to handle all these annotation !

And I don't know why you using all these dependencies in spring boot

```
     <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

All these dependencies are for spring MVC, not for spring boot ! And in spring boot there is no need to mention version for dependencies. Like

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
     </dependency>
```

You can write only like this and spring boot will automatically handle this !

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```