# Error while deploying with jdbc and web-starter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc, spring-boot-actuator, cloud-foundry

I have an application that has two dependencies, starter-jdbc and stater-web.  This runs both locally and deployed fine in PCF.  If I add starter-actuator dependency, I get the error below in PCF but no locally.  Any idea what's going on?  Thanks in advance

```
2019-07-18T08:56:25.74-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 12:56:25.742 [main] WARN org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
   2019-07-18T08:56:25.74-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 12:56:25.747 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
   2019-07-18T08:56:25.74-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
   2019-07-18T08:56:25.74-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155)
   2019-07-18T08:56:25.74-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
   2019-07-18T08:56:25.74-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
   2019-07-18T08:56:25.74-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
   2019-07-18T08:56:25.74-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
   2019-07-18T08:56:25.74-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
   2019-07-18T08:56:25.74-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
   2019-07-18T08:56:25.74-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
   2019-07-18T08:56:25.74-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.homedepot.assortment.transmission.MerchTransmissionApplication.main(MerchTransmissionApplication.java:10)
   2019-07-18T08:56:25.74-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
   2019-07-18T08:56:25.74-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:202)
   2019-07-18T08:56:25.74-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178)
   2019-07-18T08:56:25.74-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152)
   2019-07-18T08:56:25.74-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     ... 8 common frames omitted
   2019-07-18T08:56:25.77-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 1
   2019-07-18T08:56:25.77-0400 [CELL/SSHD/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2019-07-18T08:56:32.78-0400 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 3e951dff-2425-4c92-b7bb-94071ffc2ac5 stopping instance a4a2bdc5-d02e-4312-748e-8eb2
   2019-07-18T08:56:32.78-0400 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 3e951dff-2425-4c92-b7bb-94071ffc2ac5 destroying container for instance a4a2bdc5-d02e-4312-748e-8eb2
   2019-07-18T08:56:32.81-0400 [API/4] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231736/applicationcontextexception-unable-to-start-servletwebserverapplicationcontext)

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  I also tried where you have to derive your application class and no luck.

Comment: Then provide more information to determinate your error. dependencies and configurations.