# Spring Boot Library project not picking External file configuration from /conf folder

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Am migrating spring application to spring boot.Some configuration need to be set as external.Those files are place in /conf folder where the jar file exist.I have more than one project,one is parent and others are library project.Parent and library project could not pick /conf folder configuration files.

current project structure after migrate

[image]

Parent project Main class Configuration

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.data.*" })
@Profile(ContextProfileNames.SERVICE)
@ImportResource(locations = {
        "/conf/spring/service-config.xml",
        "/conf/spring/datasource-config.xml"

})
public class ServiceMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ServiceMain.class)
                .properties("spring.config.name:application.properties",
                        "spring.config.location=/conf/application.properties")
                .build()
                .run(args);
        for (String name : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {

        }

    }
}
```

Library project configuration

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationFactory
{
    public static final String extConfPath="/conf";

    public static final String REQ_CONF = extConfPath+"/Configuration.xml";
    public static final String FILTER_XML_CONF = extConfPath+"/DocFilter.xml";
}
```

Error Log

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \conf\Configuration.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:221)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:276)
    at
```

**EDIT 1**

Parent project Main class Configuration

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.data.*" })
@Profile(ContextProfileNames.SERVICE)
@ImportResource(locations = {
        "conf/spring/service-config.xml",
        "conf/spring/datasource-config.xml"

})
public class ServiceMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ServiceMain.class)
                .properties("spring.config.name:application.properties",
                        "spring.config.location=conf/application.properties")
                .build()
                .run(args);
        for (String name : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {

        }

    }
}
```

Library project configuration

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationFactory
{
    public static final String extConfPath="conf";

    public static final String REQ_CONF = extConfPath+"/Configuration.xml";
    public static final String FILTER_XML_CONF = extConfPath+"/DocFilter.xml";
}
```

now its getting another error

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.7.RELEASE)

00:26:01.203 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Loading source class com.data.services.api.ServiceMain
00:26:01.266 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2c42e416
00:26:01.297 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
00:26:01.339 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory'
00:26:01.631 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor'
00:26:01.631 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
00:26:01.631 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
00:26:01.631 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
00:26:01.631 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor'
00:26:01.647 [main] DEBUG o.s.ui.context.support.UiApplicationContextUtils - Unable to locate ThemeSource with name 'themeSource': using default [org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource@d935005]
00:26:01.647 [main] WARN  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.

00:26:01.662 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at com.ge.hcit.xer.app.services.api.XERServiceMain.main(XERServiceMain.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:203)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at com.ge.hcit.xer.app.services.api.XERServiceMain.main(XERServiceMain.java:29)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:203)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153)
    ... 12 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

**EDIT 2**

How can i use spring.config.location instead of hardcoding the values in import resources and application.pproperties using the below comment.How can i read **spring.config.location** in java side

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=D:/Springboot/conf
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: For your second edit, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25862357/4929038

Answer (score 0):

Do not use slash at the beginning of the path, it will point to the root of the drive (both on [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats) and Linux). Having the path without the slash (`conf/application.properties`) should work, as it will be a relative path then.

Comment: I have changed ,based on your comments.now getting another error.

Comment: A quick google search links to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231736/applicationcontextexception-unable-to-start-servletwebserverapplicationcontext/50232382) SO topic. Hope it helps.

Comment: undeestood that point.I can able to load application.property file but unable to import external xml files using @ImportantResource()