# Why am I getting error while starting my spring-boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am unable to start my spring-boot app. Getting error

```
Unable to start web server; nested exception is 
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start
ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
```

Have tried everything from internet. `@SpringBootApplication` is present in main class and it extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class ServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Please suggest what is missing?

Below are the dependencies added in my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>DigitalConnectCheckInLib</groupId>
    <artifactId>digital-connect-check-in-lib</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.selfservice.jetblue</groupId>
    <artifactId>b6-dcci-client</artifactId>
    <version>${cts.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: May be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231736/applicationcontextexception-unable-to-start-servletwebserverapplicationcontext/50232382 can help

Comment: What starters are you using? (Web, Webflux, ...)

Comment: @Saurabh I have followed that link already and tried everything. Just 1 thing I did not do, that is setting web application type to none. I cannot do that as mine is a web application.

Comment: @jBuchholz, let me paste my pom.xml here.

Comment: @AanchalArora Are you having an external server deployment.Could you share the entire stacktrace and your `pom.xml`

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhan, when I tried to deploy it as a war in tomcat, it worked. But starting it as a Java Application is giving error.