# Using RestTemplate on DesktopApplication (Non-WebBased)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am working on a Desktop Application, with `OpenJfx` and `SpringBoot`. It works well thus far.

However, this application will consume a WebService and I want to use RestTemplate. When I add `spring-web` dependency to my pom.xml file, Spring Boot attempts to instantiate several things for which I do not have use.

The dependency added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

First, the following error is displayed:

```
[2020-08-11 10:26:20] - WARN  - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean. [AbstractApplicationContext.java:558]
```

I added the following propery, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50232382/4150785) response:

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

Running the application again, more things attempt to instantiate:

```
[2020-08-11 10:29:47] - WARN  - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jacksonObjectMapper' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.visibility(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/PropertyAccessor;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect$Visibility;)Lorg/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder; [AbstractApplicationContext.java:558] 
[2020-08-11 10:29:47] - INFO  - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. [ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.java:136] 
[2020-08-11 10:29:47] - ERROR - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration$StandardJackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer.configureVisibility(JacksonAutoConfiguration.java:258)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.visibility(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/PropertyAccessor;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect$Visibility;)Lorg/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;

The method's class, org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
 [LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter.java:40]
```

The problem is, I only want to use RestTemplate to consume a Rest Service. Is there a way I can add Classes native to other spring libraries, without all the additional baggage?

Answer (score 0):

`RestTemplate` is only a wrapper around a `HttpClient` implementation. That http client needs to be provided by someone for example an underlying server implementation like tomcat, undertow, netty, jetty etc. But can also come from a standalone client.

So if we walk through your errors:

```
[2020-08-11 10:26:20] - WARN  - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean. [AbstractApplicationContext.java:558]
```

This says that it can't start a server, because you have pulled in `spring-web` which is a lot of classes that needs a server. It tries to `autostart` a lot of classes.

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

So with this parameter you basically disable all the `autostart` classes that will get run if you have a web application. This will not disable the creation of the spring context (the context is needed to create all spring classes, to make sure autowiring works, beans etc etc)

```sh
[2020-08-11 10:29:47] - WARN  - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jacksonObjectMapper' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.visibility(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/PropertyAccessor;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect$Visibility;)Lorg/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder; [AbstractApplicationContext.java:558]
```

So when you run it now it tries to create the context and fails because it can't find `Jackson` because jackson is needed and is created using the `autostart` classes that **you disabled with your  previous parameter**.

Its basically saying you want to use a car, but you don't want the engine, wheels, interior, doors, steering wheel etc. etc. If you don't have a server or anything for that matter that provides the HttpClient there is nothing for `RestTemplate` to use or wrap around.

If you are looking for a standalone simple rest client i would suggest looking into [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)