# Missing ServletWebServerFactory Spring Boot Bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, sqlite, hibernate

I am currently learning spring boot but i have a small issue concerning the running of my server
below is the code

**My springJPA Application class**

```
@Configuration
public class SpringJpaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringJpaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**This is my controller***

```
@Controller
public class IssuesController {
    
    @Autowired
    IssueRepository repo; 
    
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "home.jsp"; 
}
    
    @RequestMapping("/addIssue")
    public ModelAndView addIssue(Issues issue) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(); 
        
        mv.addObject("obj", issue); 
        mv.setViewName("home");
        
        repo.save(issue);
        return mv; 
    }
    
}
```

**this are the application properties i made in order to be able to use SQLite in my demo application**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
 
 
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:sqlite:sqlitesample.db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.sqlite.JDBC
 
spring.datasource.username = admin
spring.datasource.password = admin
spring.sql.init.mode = always
```

Lastly, these are some of the dependencies i added

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoApplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springJPA</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
     <version>9.0.48</version>
     </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

However, I keep on getting this error when I try to run the application

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.example.demo.SpringJpaApplication.main(SpringJpaApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:210) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231736/applicationcontextexception-unable-to-start-servletwebserverapplicationcontext/50232382), seems you're missing the annotation @SpringBootApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringJpaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringJpaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: i tried doing what you suggested but i am now getting a new error.  this time an application context error.

Comment: Then please post the whole error and code. This error can be related to missing Spring Annotations or wrong jdbc settings, or many other stuff.