# Java Springboot "Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext" error

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I know there are several posts out there about this, but nothing helped me specifically. I have a Java Springboot rest API that runs fine on localhost but throws an error when trying to run as a jar.

Here is my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HarrierApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(HarrierApplication.class, args);
    }
```

Here is the output when I try and run a jar file:

```
21:03:35.089 [main] DEBUG o.s.u.c.s.UiApplicationContextUtils - Unable to locate ThemeSource with name 'themeSource': using default [org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource@3e681bc]
21:03:35.089 [main] WARN  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
21:03:35.093 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)
        at com.me.harrier.HarrierApplication.main(HarrierApplication.java:20)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:205)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:177)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:158)
        ... 8 common frames omitted
```

My pom.xml is a mess from all of my attempts to fix this, but here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>harrier</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>harrier</name>
    <description>Harrier App</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR5</spring-cloud.version>
        <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
        <start-class>com.me.harrier.HarrierApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--        For controller jwt authentication-->
        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bitbucket.b_c</groupId>
            <artifactId>jose4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.2</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <!--            SMS messages-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
            <version>7.54.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For validation (@Valid) in controller -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JWT token library-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
<!--            use Hikari CP for connection pooling instead of Tomcat-->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
<!--            <version>1.11.828</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>-->
<!--            <exclusions>-->
<!--                <exclusion>-->
<!--                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>-->
<!--                </exclusion>-->
<!--            </exclusions>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>log4j</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.2.17</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation for email notifications-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ses</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.415</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.665</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>coverage-initialize</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>coverage-report</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>coverage-check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>CLASS</element>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>com.asimio.demo.Application</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Please check this, if you haven't seen it earlier,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231736/applicationcontextexception-unable-to-start-servletwebserverapplicationcontext

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your all dependency in with java 8 and java 11 I could not find any issues. Did you add any additional properties in property file as like below.

```
Spring.main.web-application-type= none
```

If so then remove it.

I show you have tomcat dependency remove that one became spring core tomcat itself.

If you have any additional configuration please ping that also.