# Can't run my jar after upgrading SpringBoot from 2.4.X to 2.6.X

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jar, executable-jar

I upgraded my library recently from gradle 5.X to 7.3.1 and upgraded Spring-Boot from 2.4.X to 2.6.X but I'm facing an issues. I was using gradle build to create a jar and execute this jar on my server and that was working fine with Spring-Boot 2.4.X but now with 2.6.X I got some issues:

> no main manifest attribute

So I added to my build.gradle

```
jar {
   manifest {
       attributes "Main-Class": "my.package.MainClass"
   }

   from {
       configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
       configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
   }
}
```

And now i'm getting the error

> Could not find or load main class my.package.MainClass

If I'm switching back to 2.4.X it's working fine.
My jar from :

- spring-boot 2.4.X -> 90Mo
- spring-boot 2.6.X -> 500 Ko

So I tried to create a fat jar with shadowJar and got this error

> ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
> Dec 21 10:04:09 vps-11602ed1 project[12706]: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.

If someone got an answer about how to make it works with Spring-boot 2.6.X.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231736/applicationcontextexception-unable-to-start-servletwebserverapplicationcontext

Comment: I tried:
- My main class got @SpringBootApplication and already extends from SpringBootServletInitializer
- added to every profile spring.main.web-application-type=none
- Case 3 already done aswell
- I'm not using tomcat
- I'm building from a gitlab VM so don't need to repackage or clean
- Tried to add spring-boot-starter-parent
- spring.profiles.active=default
Nothing works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. When I'm upgrading from springboot 2.4.X to 2.6.X, now gradle build is generating a new jar "plain" with my casual jar. And I renamed my jar to the same name. So instead of using the biggest jar, I was using the smallest. Just added that to my gradle.build:

```
jar {
enabled = false
}
```

So now, it's not creating the "plain" jar and everything is working fine