# SpringBoot app fails to start with weird exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, ubuntu

My freshly-created app written on springboot-2.7.1 fails to start with the following error

> Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/abondar/.sdkman/candidates/java/21.3.0.r17-grl/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Absolutely weird. I have another app writeen 0n 2.6.3 running perfectly on the same jvm. Also downgrading of this app to 2.6.3 doesn't help.

Here is build.gradle

```
    plugins {
    id "java"
    id "idea"
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "$springBootVersion"
}

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

group "org.abondar.experimental.cameldemo"
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'


    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
implementation('ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.11')


testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

bootBuildImage {
    imageName = "abondar/shoppingCart"
}
```

From logs I can see the following

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
> start web server; nested exception is
> org.springframework.boot.web.context.MissingWebServerFactoryBeanException:
> No qualifying bean of type
> 'org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory'
> available: Unable to start
> AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing
> ServletWebServerFactory bean 681 [main] ERROR
> o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter -

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is this answer helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50232382/7833793

Answer (score 0):

Made a dummy mistake in main.

Was failing because of

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.class,args);
  }
```